# How do would you split this NSString into a NSDictionary?

Tags: objective-c, arrays, nsmutablearray, nsmutabledictionary

I have some data i aquire from some linux box and want to put it into a NSDictionary for later processing.

How wold you get this NSString into a NSDictionary like the following?

```
data (
eth0 (Errors => 0, Bytes => 32, Packtes => 0, Index => 2,...)
eth1 (Errors => 0, Bytes => 32, Packtes => 0, Index => 2,...)
lo (Errors => 0, Bytes => 32, Packtes => 0, Index => 2,...)
...)
```

Each value should be accessable like:

```
NSString eth0_errors = [[data objectForKey:@"eth0"] objectForKey:@"Errors"];
```

The data string looks like:

```
NSString *dummydata = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"+ 1\n"
                       "eth0 Errors 0\n"
                       "eth0 Bytes 34\n"
                       "eth0 Packets 0\n"
                       "eth0 Index 2\n"
                       "eth0 Type ETHER\n"
                       "eth0 MAC 00:0c:29:39:81:9c\n"
                       "eth0 MTU 1500\n"
                       "eth0 Broadcast ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff\n"
                       "eth0 Base-Addr 00000000\n"
                       "eth0 IRQ 0\n"
                       "eth0 Realm intern\n"
                       "eth0 Flags UP BROADCAST\n"
                       "eth0 Features HW-CSUM HW-VLAN-TX HW-VLAN-RX HW-VLAN-FILTER\n"
                       "eth0 Speed 1000Mb/s\n"
                       "eth0 Duplex Full\n"
                       "eth0 Negotiation on\n"
                       "eth0 Link up\n"
                       "eth0 Switch\n"
                       "eth1 Errors 0\n"
                       "eth1 Bytes 0\n"
                       "eth1 Packets 0\n"
                       "eth1 Index 3\n"
                       "eth1 Type ETHER\n"
                       "eth1 MAC 00:0c:29:39:81:a6\n"
                       "eth1 MTU 1500\n"
                       "eth1 Broadcast ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff\n"
                       "eth1 Base-Addr 00000000\n"
                       "eth1 IRQ 0\n"
                       "eth1 Realm unknown\n"
                       "eth1 Flags BROADCAST\n"
                       "eth1 Features SG/IO HW-CSUM HW-VLAN-TX HW-VLAN-RX HW-VLAN-FILTER\n"
                       "eth1 Negotiation on\n"
                       "eth1 Link DOWN\n"
                       "eth1 Switch\n"
                       "eth1 Speed ?\n"
                       "eth1 Duplex ?\n"
                       "lo Errors 0\n"
                       "lo Bytes 79\n"
                       "lo Packets 1\n"
                       "lo Index 1\n"
                       "lo Type LOOPBACK\n"
                       "lo MAC 00:00:00:00:00:00\n"
                       "lo MTU 3500\n"
                       "lo Broadcast 00:00:00:00:00:00\n"
                       "lo Base-Addr 00000000\n"
                       "lo IRQ 0\n"
                       "lo Realm opsys\n"
                       "lo Flags UP LOOPBACK\n"
                       "lo Features SG/IO NO-CSUM HIGH-DMA FRAGLIST\n"
                       "lo Link up\n"
                       "lo Switch\n"
                       "lo Speed ?\n"
                       "lo Duplex ?\n"
                       "lo Negotiation ?\n"
                       ".\n"];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming your data will always be compliant with the format you specified, you could use something like this:

```
NSArray *components = [dummydata componentsSeparatedByString:@"\n"];
NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];

for(NSString *component in components) {
    NSArray *subcomponents = [component componentsSeparatedByString:@" "];

    if(subcomponents.count >= 3) {
        NSMutableDictionary *subdictionary = [dictionary objectForKey:[subcomponents objectAtIndex:0]];

        if(subdictionary == nil) {
            subdictionary = [NSMutableDictionary new];
            [dictionary setObject:subdictionary forKey:[subcomponents objectAtIndex:0]];
        }

        if(subcomponents.count > 3) {
            [subdictionary setObject:[subcomponents subarrayWithRange:NSMakeRange(2, subcomponents.count - 2)] forKey:[subcomponents objectAtIndex:1]];
        } else {
            [subdictionary setObject:[subcomponents objectAtIndex:2] forKey:[subcomponents objectAtIndex:1]];
        }
    }
}
```

Note that numeric values will be represented as NSStrings. If you want them to be NSNumbers instead, you will need to perform additional checks and conversions within the loop.

Comment: Mark my answer so that your question no longer shows up as unanswered.